# Accessing html tag attributes

Tags: html, dom, tags

I'm trying to test a very basic javascript function that will only remove an attribute from an input. In this case, i want the placeholder attribute to be removed, and this is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function buttonClicked() {
    document.getElementById("textBox").removeAttribute('placeholder');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="commentBox">
        <input type="textarea" rows="4" cols="50">
</div>
<div id="textBox">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Write">
</div>
<div id="shoutButton">
    <input type="button" value="Shout!" onclick="buttonClicked();">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `#textBox` does not have a placeholder attribute!

Answer (score 2):

In the provided code "textBox" is the id of the `div` element which wraps your `input`. You need to get the input instead. Try setting the id of the input as well:

```
<div id="textBox">
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Write">
</div>
```

Then update your buttonClicked function to use the input's id:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    document.getElementById("input").removeAttribute('placeholder');
}
```

Comment: figures this out immediately after posting, lol truly sorry for asking such basic thing